# Как в экселе разбить содержание в ячейке разделенные запятыми в отдельные строки?

Tags: excel

Есть ячейка с "1,2,3", мне надо получить три строки с 1 2 3 содержимым.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to split single text cell into multiple rows, using a comma delimiter?](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/356492-how-split-single-text-cell-into-multiple-rows-using-comma-delimiter.html)

Вот нашел! Спасибо всем.

Answer (score 0):

здесь проще, без VBA

http://www.kak-v.com/formula-esli-v-eksel-denned-svodnye-tablicy/

Answer (score 0):

Вдруг кому пригодится.

В строке 1 тексты для разбивки.

```
=СЖПРОБЕЛЫ(ПСТР(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A$1;",";ПОВТОР(" ";50));(СТРОКА(A1)-1)*50+1;50))
```

Формула разнесет по строкам все значения, разделеные запятой.

Препарируем.

Разделяем нужные фрагменты множеством пробелов:

```
ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A$1;",";ПОВТОР(" ";50))
```

Извлекаем фрагменты построчно. Фрагменты с "мусором" (пробелами):

```
ПСТР(разделенные_пробелами_фрагменты;(СТРОКА(A1)-1)*50+1;50)
```

Чистим от "мусора":

```
СЖПРОБЕЛЫ(пробелы_фрагмент_пробелы)
```